# Creating multiple users in bash shell from a csv file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to create multiple users from a csv file from a bash shell script. My csv looks like this

```
Codigo,Apellido,Nombre,Carrera,Facultad,Rol 
10001,Accorti,Paolo,COM,FACED,Profesor
10002,Afonso,Pedro,ICI,FIA,Estudiante
.
.
.
```

I have the following code

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read  -r Codigo Apellido Nombre Carrera Facultad Rol; 
do

password="Pass123"
sudo useradd -c "${Codigo} ${Apellido}" -d "/home/$codigo" -s /bin/bash -p "${password}"

done < Usuarios.csv
```

When I run the code, I don't have any error but my terminal shows options for useradd and my accounts have not been created. This is my first time programming in bash shell, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: shouldn't ```-d "/home/$codigo"``` be ```-d "/home/$Codigo"```?

Comment: As pointed out in some answers: -p is used wrong (you should pass a crypted password). But the main problem is: useradd is missing an argument for the login name.

man page:
useradd [options] LOGIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your command for "useradd" is wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read  -r Codigo Apellido Nombre Carrera Facultad Rol; 
do

  password="Pass123"
  useradd -c "${Codigo} ${Apellido}" -m -p ${password} -s /bin/bash ${Codigo}

done < Usuarios.csv
```

Comment: I've tried that and the users are not being created

Comment: It's strange because for me it's working fine.
Did you use exactly same line like in my post for "useradd" command ?
What error did you receive ?

Comment: I was getting useradd command not found but adding a sudo before it made it work, thank you so much!

Comment: Ahh I missed sudo , sorry ;)
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the man pages for useradd:

```
  -p, --password PASSWORD
       The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to
       disable the password.

       Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or
       encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.

       You should make sure the password respects the system's password
       policy.
```

The password when passed with -p will need to be encrypted and cannot be plain text. The alternative will be to use passwd

Another possibility would be to user newusers, although this is distribution specific.

Comment: I've tried that too and still have the same result in the terminal, the users are not being created.

Comment: How are you encrypting the password?